# |Appium - Ruby| How does one assert that certain text is not displayed on the screen

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, watir-webdriver, appium-ios

In a scenario I want to assert that text "Something" is not displayed on the screen.

This is a test for mobile iOS app. 
It is a Appium test, in Cucumber + Watir-Webdriver. Steps are written in Ruby.

This is what I have attempted so far with RSpec expectations:

## 1

```
    Given /^I should NOT see text "([^"]*)" displayed$/ do |text|
  text_exact(text).displayed? == false
end
```

## 2

```
Given /^I should NOT see text "([^"]*)" displayed$/ do |text|
  expect(nil).to eq(text)
end
```

## 3

```
Given /^I should NOT see text "([^"]*)" displayed$/ do |text|
  expect('Something').to_not eq(text)
end
```

## 4

```
Given /^I should NOT see text "([^"]*)" displayed$/ do |text|
  expect(text).to eq(false)
end
```

Seems there are plenty of examples for the element when is displayed. However, when you want to assert that certain text is not displayed then there a lack of information. 
Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

All of the examples are comparing text from the step definition with a fixed value. You should be comparing text from the step definition to text retrieved from the browser.

The simplest approach is to check if the text is not included anywhere in the browser's text:

```
expect(browser.text).not_to include(text)
```

However, this can lead to false negatives if the page is large and/or the text is not unique. For example, say the page is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span id="error">Something wrong</span>
    <span>Something else</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

If having "Something wrong" is bad, but having "Something else" is okay, checking the entire browser text will fail. In this case, it would be better to scope the text to a specific element that should not have the text:

```
expect(browser.span(id: 'error').text).not_to include(text)
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. This is iOS mobile app. What could I use besides `browser.text` ?

Comment: You are using Watir-Webdriver, right? `browser` would be whatever variable you used to store the `Watir::Browser` instance?

Comment: Yes.  browser = Watir::Browser.new DRIVER.to_sym, :http_client => client

Comment: This is my step: `Given /^I should NOT see text "([^"]*)" displayed$/ do |text|
  expect(browser.text).not_to include(text)
end
`   and this is Gherkin: `And I should NOT see text "Something" displayed` . I do get an error: `undefined local variable or method `browser' for #<AppiumWorld:0x00000101e97f30> (NameError)
`

Comment: Sorry, my experience with Appium is pretty limited. Within the steps, how are you interacting the app - eg clicking links and inputting forms? I would expected you would have needed to access the `browser` there.

Comment: It opens the iOS simulator from Xcode and then performs the test. I have added browser and this opens Xcode simulator and Chrome browser with an empty value in search bar. This approach doesnt seem to work for mobile app as test is passing in any case. Thanks anyway

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any tests that assert that a specified text is displayed?

Comment: Yes: **#1** `Given(/^I must see text "([^"]*)" displayed$/) do |text|
  wait { text_exact text }
end` **#2** `Given /^I should see text "([^"]*)" displayed$/ do |text|
  expect('Some text').to eq(text)
end`                                                                                                             **#3**  `Given(/^I should see the title "([^"]*)" displayed$/) do |arg1|
  find_element(:xpath, arg1).displayed? == true
end`

Comment: I think you might want to double-check your usages. From what I can see, your steps are using Appium directly instead of Watir-Webdriver - ie you are declaring `browser` but never actually using it. Addressing that should allow you to use the suggested code.

Comment: Nope Justin, that would not work with simulator. Thanks for the effort and trying to help out

Comment: i use selenium and just calling `texts` returns the visible texts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Appium, but it should be something like:

`expect(foo).to_not include(text)`

Where `foo` is the text you're checking against.

(`to_not`, or the equivalent `not_to`, will negate the following matcher).

Answer (score 0):

solution is located in Appium/Issues, here:
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6675